# ReplaceAll java throws exception

Tags: java, regex

why does this code throw an exception?

```
file = file.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/"),File.separator);
```

```
Message: String index out of range: 1
File: null Class: java.lang.String Methode: charAt Line: -1
File: null Class: java.util.regex.Matcher Methode: appendReplacement Line: -1
File: null Class: java.util.regex.Matcher Methode: replaceAll Line: -1
File: null Class: java.lang.String Methode: replaceAll Line: -1
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard Java stacktrace.  What platform are you on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter of `replaceAll` is *also* a pattern to some extent. In particular, backslash has a special meaning. However, you don't just want to use `Pattern.quote` as that will quote more than you need to. You want to use `Matcher.quoteReplacement`:

```
file = file.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("/"), 
                       Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator));
```

Alternatively - and rather more simply - don't use regular expressions at all:

```
file = file.replace("/", File.separator);
```

Comment: don't you want Matcher.quoteReplacement()? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Reading the API helps, i though replace only replaces the first finding... That makes things easier :-)